# extracting a table value and list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a table, in one of the columns all the values are presented in lists. At the same time, in each row in this column there is a list in which there is only one value. how do I get this value out by creating a new column or changing it.
example:

```
| left | center | right |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| One  | Two    | [123] |
| One  | Two    | [234] |
| One  | Two    | [12.5]|
```

result

```
| left | center | right |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| One  | Two    | 123   |
| One  | Two    | 234   |
| One  | Two    | 12.5  |
```

Comment: what's the data type of that column? for arrays, see `getItem()` column method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyspark method element_at https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.element_at.html

so if you have the Dataframe df can turn it into result by:

```
result = df.withColumn("right", element_at(df.right, 1))
```